# how to stop accessing css and js from url in static folder ? Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I just added all my css and js files in static folder and it could be easily accessed from url, how can I fix it? I added this method to my security configuration

```
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
   web
            .ignoring()
            .antMatchers("/resources/**");
}
```

but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Assuming for an example that you don't want to expose `/static/that/` folder.

Rather than *Blacklist* approach I suggest selectively define a *Whitelist* of your resources like below (where you don't define say `/static/that/`)

```
spring.resources.static-locations=classpath:/META-INF/resources/,classpath:/resources/,classpath:/static/this/,classpath:/public/ # Locations of static resources.
```

Excert of code above, taken from [Spring Boot Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#common-application-properties)